# Stack Exchange site to ask Health and Medical related questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask Health and Medical related questions on this site?

Is there a stackexchange site to ask questions about **Health** and **Medical** ?

Answer (score 7):

There's the [Health](http://health.stackexchange.com) site currently available. A simple site search should have you taken there.

Be sure to take [the tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) there before asking. Also you might want to read about their policies from the Help Center.

I'd guess you shouldn't ask for medical advice or diagnosis there, go to a doctor instead.

Answer (score 6):

[image: GIF showing how simple it is to find the desired site by searching for 'health' in the site switcher]

Comment: What tool you used to capture this `gif` file?

Comment: @Arul that's Licecap :)

Comment: Your answer isn't very useful for people who can't see the image.

Comment: @AlE. Sort of edited :)

Comment: I hate ignorant trolls who write like this. Perhaps the question asker, like myself, saw the one called "Medical Sciences" that comes up, and wanted to know if there was another more specific one they missed WHEN they searched. Have you been shoved in a locker one too many times?