# Adding a link with a space in front causes the link to not work

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, editor

When you paste a link into the "Insert Hyperlink" box, it adds it automatically as a citation link:

```
[Example 1][1]

  [1]: http://example.com
```

But when you paste a link starting with a space , it tries to URL encode it, to change the space to `%20`, and then sticks a `http://` on the front to make it a valid link:

```
[Example 2][2]

  [2]: http://%20http://example.com
```

This, however, means the link doesn't work.

[image]

Please could leading whitespace be stripped from the URL?

Comment: Unrelated but what tool did you use to make the gif? Was it a simple process? I'd be curious :-)

Comment: @enderland: I don't have idea about which tool **Tim** used. But there is a tool called [Licecap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271768/stack-exchange-site-to-ask-health-and-medical-related-questions/271770#comment881810_271770) can do the same.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, there are a *lot* of people who use the "insert link" box and copy-paste in a link with a leading space.  This leads to a large amount of broken links.  See e.g. this SEDE query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/688578/858478/hrefhttp-20 ... or this Stackoverflow query: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2f%2520%22

Comment: @enderland Fwiw (old comment) I'm a huge fan of http://www.screentogif.com/, myself. Also, regardless of tool used, if the gifs turn out too big another good post-processing workflow tool is https://ezgif.com/optimize.

Comment: @enderland this was Peek for Ubuntu. LiceCap is excellent on Windows.

Comment: Hmm, I think I posted about this more recently, but the behavior is different now, yet still annoying https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382174/can-we-strip-preceding-whitespace-out-and-check-for-https-being-present-whe  It won't URL encode it, but will add `https://` in front of the link, so you end up with `https:// https://somelink`