# What causes "http://%20https://" links to be made?

Tags: support, broken-link

See the revision history [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/271692/revisions) on a post from 2016. There is this edit by our resident hero Glorfindel:

[image: Described below]

The edit fixed this link, made up of a URL but with two schemes and %20 between them (a URL encoding of a space):

`http://%20https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/my-account/device-activation-deactivation/about-device-activation/`

replacing it with

`https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/my-account/device-activation-deactivation/about-device-activation/`

**What caused all of these broken links to be put in posts? Can some automated process fix the remaining ones?** There are a lot of them around the sites.

Comment: Dunno what a "security protocol" is but it ain't that

Comment: Related on [meta.ubuntu.se]: [Broken links starting with http://%20https://](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18803/broken-links-starting-with-http-20https)

Answer (score 34):

<sub>*humbly accepts compliment*</sub>

I *suspect* it's caused by users who copy/paste a link from elsewhere, but accidentally select too much text, more specifically an extra space in front of the link. Like this:

[image]

Do you see the difference? I don't, and that's exactly why these broken links happen. The insert dialog above produces the following link:

[enter link description here](http://%20https://meta.stackexchange.com)

(clicking it won't work, since it's broken; you can check the source code of this post and it'll show you that it's `http://%20https://meta.stackexchange.com`)

---

> **Can some automated process fix the remaining ones?**

I've been toying with this for a while. It's possible to search for [`url:%20http`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%2520http) to find (most of) these posts; that's how I found the example you mentioned. I've written a userscript (maybe I'll publish it someday, right now it's a bit of a mess) which checks posts I'm editing for broken links of this type and tries to fix them. Also, a variation of the [Broken Image Repairer](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f) is running on the non-English Stack Overflow sites, fixing those links ([here are some examples](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223536/glorfindel?tab=activity&sort=revisions)).

The main problem with automated processes is that sometimes the links are broken anyway, even if they had been inserted correctly, and I try to improve other things (grammar/spelling, converting HTTP links to HTTPS) while I'm bumping the post.

---

Oh, while we're in compliment mode: the user who (probably unknowingly) inspired my crusade against broken links is [@Pang](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/204869/pang), after I saw a couple of their edits across the network.

Comment: You have earned the **Resident Hero** badge for **[What causes “http://%20https://” links to be made?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337401/164403)** See **[your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel)**.

Comment: Gives me a place to thank you for fixing a number of those in my answers on Mi Yodeya. I did wonder how the errors got in there as I typically copy these links with a Cmd-L Cmd-C, and since many of the links you fixed were amazon references, I wonder if this is not the automated SE script that changed those links

Comment: What if the system trimmed the spaces before you submitted the URL? 

Comment: @Laurel sounds like a good [tag:feature-request]!

Comment: @Glorfindel it’s already been suggested apparently. [Upvotes anyone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273213/323179)?

Comment: Heh ... you would think I should remember that post, given I edited it recently, but that was part of a serial rollback.

Comment: I imagine the other possible cause is that folks hit the button/hotkey to insert a link – but then, instead of *replacing* the URL placeholder of `https://` (or `http://`, before the editor was updated to match the shift to HTTPS), they simply inserted the intended URL *after* that placeholder.